# How add feature into GeoServer

Tags: rest, postgis, geoserver

I'm using the GeoServer 2.9 and I created the datastore, workspace and layer. I want to add a feature into GeoServer using GeoServer REST API. I didn't find any API to add features into a layer (which I create). Can anyone help me how to add a feature into GeoServer using REST API!?

Answer (score 0):

First, please upgrade to a recent GeoServer version, currently 2.13.x and 2.14.x are supported versions.

There is **no way to add a feature to a layer** using the REST API. However, depending on the layer type you can add a feature to the underlying datastore and GeoServer will render it next time a map of that layer is requested.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply , than how to add feature into layer from out side .

Comment: depends on what your source is - for example you can add a row to a database table